# Node JS: What's the difference Between open file in write mode and write mode

Tags: node.js

I know that write mode can write things but what does open() in write mode do?

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.open('mynewfile2.txt', 'w', function (err, file) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Saved!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

File open with `w` flag refers to:-

> Open file for writing. The file is created (if it does not exist) or
>   truncated (if it exists).

For more information please refer [Link](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback)

Comment: Doesn't this mean same as write mode? Both can be used for writing.

Comment: with open you can specify what you want to do with the file using flags, on the other hand, write offers 2 methods:-
1. fs.write(fd, buffer[, offset[, length[, position]]], callback) // writing buffer to file
2. fs.write(fd, string[, position[, encoding]], callback) // write string to file
yes if you only want to write you can use both